# Are indexes built CONCURRENTLY different in any way?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, concurrency

Does PostgreSQL `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` mean that even after initial index build, new and future inserts won't be indexed immediately (strongly consistent in terms of indexing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [`CREATE INDEX`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) with the modifier `CONCURRENTLY` produces exactly the same kind of index as without the modifier.

`CONCURRENTLY` only changes the way the index is created initially, meaning it does not block concurrent writes. A side effect is that creating the index can take considerably longer than without `CONCURRENTLY`, especially under concurrent write load (which would otherwise be blocked until the command is done).

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#id-1.9.3.69.6)

> `CONCURRENTLY`
>
> When this option is used, PostgreSQL will build the index without
> taking any locks that prevent concurrent inserts, updates, or deletes
> on the table; whereas a standard index build locks out writes (but not
> reads) on the table until it's done.  There are several caveats to be
> aware of when using this option — see [Building Indexes
> Concurrently](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY) below.

Follow the quoted link for details.